# How to improve the visualization quality of a pie chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, label, pie-chart

I have some data in I want to do a pie chart from it. In the data, there is a category that is to low and its label on the chart does not look good. My code and the respective plot are the following.

```
library("readr")
library("fmsb")
library("car")
library("normtest")
library("nortest")
library("moments")
library("readxl")   
library("ggplot2")
library("stats")
library("data.table")
library("dplyr")
library("plotly")

count.data <- data.frame(
  Tópico = c("Problemas de ruteo", "Diseño de redes ", "Ruteo y localización", "Modelos de inventario","Problemas de localización","Problemas de asignación","Medición de riesgo"),
  n = c(27,6,16,10,31,6,4),
  prop = c(27,6,16,10,31,6,4)
)
count.data

count.data <- count.data %>%
  arrange(desc(Tópico)) %>%
  mutate(lab.ypos = cumsum(prop) - 0.5*prop)
count.data

mycols <- c("#A1E89D", "#EFC000FF", "#868686FF", "#CD534CFF","#7AD55D","#9333FF","#FF33CE")

ggplot(count.data, aes(x = "", y = prop, fill =Tópico)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1.8, stat = "identity", color = "black") +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0)+
  geom_text(aes(y = lab.ypos, label = paste0(prop, "%")), color = "black",cex=3.5)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = mycols)+ theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())+theme_void()
```

The plot is:

[image]

As you can see, the category in yellow does not look good, in general, I would like to change the style of these labels, for example, this way:

[image]

Of course, I would like to preserve the legends, any ideas?. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution using Plotly.

```
plot_ly(count.data, labels = ~count.data$n, values = ~count.data$n, type = 'pie',
        textposition = 'outside',
        textinfo = 'label',
        insidetextfont = list(color = '#FFFFFF'),
        hoverinfo = 'text',
        marker = list(line = list(color = '#FFFFFF', width = 1)),showlegend = TRUE)
```

[image]